# Problem file naming when dowloading the file

Tags: node.js, angular, excel, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

this is my first stack post, sorry if it's a little blurry :/

So basically I have a Angular project with firestore behind. I got a cloud function which generates an **.xlsx** file and upload it to my fireStorage.

```
    const path = 'hellothere/excels';
    return workBook.xlsx.writeFile(`/tmp/myExcel.xlsx`).then(() => {
      return storageFb.upload( `/tmp/myexcel.xlsx`,{
        destination: path+'/myExcel.xlsx',
      }
      )
    }).then(() => path);
```

Where **StorageFb** is the bucket of my storage.

Actuelly it's working, it uploads my **.xlsx** file under */hellothere/excels/* with the name *myExcel.xlsx*. But when I download it (by the admin panel or my angular client), it is fully named *hellothere_excels_myExcel.xlsx*.

Here is my client code:

```
this.fireStorage.ref('hellothere/excels/myExcel.xlsx').getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
      window.open(url, '_blank');
  });
   return Promise.resolve();
```

Simply. I know the code is messy but i'm testing all solution I can find so i'll clean it up afterall

[Admin panel path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FytvD.png)

[My file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyHAT.png)

So I'm kinda stuck since I dunno why those file won't download with just the 'myExcel' name.
If anyone have a clue you'll save my week ahah ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the content disposition to define the filename. Try that

```
    const path = 'hellothere/excels';
    return workBook.xlsx.writeFile(`/tmp/myExcel.xlsx`).then(() => {
      return storageFb.upload( `/tmp/myexcel.xlsx`,{
        destination: path+'/myExcel.xlsx',
        contentDisposition: 'filename=myExcel.xlsx'
      }
      )
    }).then(() => path);
```

Comment: Dang you saved me ! Thanks a lot, I would not have found it myself :) I just needed to add the 'contentDisposition' under a 'metadata' object, like that :   
metadata: {
            contentDisposition: 'filename=myExcel.xlsx'
} Thanks :)